# Rails trying to reload data after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models - Arrangement and Contact.

In my **/views/arrangements/index.html.erb** page, I'm trying to show a table of contacts.

I also have a model window with this form in it on my **arrangements/index.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for @new_to_contact, :remote => true, :id => 'new_item' do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :family_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :family_name %>
    <%= f.label :action %>
    <%= f.text_area :action, :rows => 3 %>
    <%= button_tag "Save", :type => 'submit' %>
    <%= button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'button', :data => {:dismiss => 'modal' } %>
  <% end %>
```

Here's my `arrangements_controller#index` method

```
def index
    @arrangements = Arrangement.find(:all, :order => 'location_id')
    @new_to_contact = Contact.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @arrangements }
    end
  end
```

Here's my `contacts_controller#create` method

```
def create
    @to_contact = Contact.new(params[:to_contact])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @to_contact.save
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to @to_contact, notice: 'To contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @to_contact, status: :created, location: @to_contact }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @to_contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's my **/views/contacts/create.js.erb**

```
console.log('TEST');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

My question is, how can I reload my contact list in my arrangements index file from my **create.js.erb** file?

I tried adding this line to my **create.js.erb** file, but that threw a template error:

```
$(".table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(Contact.all)) %>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Rails way, you should extract your new_contact form from arrangements/index.html.erb to contacts/_form.html.erb and render this partial inside arrangements/index.html.erb.

Then you can easily render this template from your js.erb file using something like:

```
$('.table tr:last').after("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:contact => @to_contact}) %>")
```

Comment: The reason i have a new_contact form in arrangements/index.html.erb is because I want to have a modal window where they can ajaxily add a new contact on the arrangements page without having to go to the contacts page, add a contact, and then go back to the arrangements page.

Comment: Ok i created a partial called views/contacts/_running_list.html.erb and moved my form code above into that partial. When i try adding a new contact now, i get the error `undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass` on this line of the _running_list partial `<% if @to_contacts.empty? %>`

Comment: Since, you are rendering from the JS partial now, you have to use the vars defined as locals instead of instance variables defined in controller actions. Instance vars are of course available in your JS.erb template. So, try passing this as locals in your call to render :partial

Comment: So are you saying that i need to change my partial to use `:contact` instead of directly specifying the instance variable?

Comment: Aha that worked. Thank you very much. I knew there was a "rails" way to do this that i wasn't doing correctly.

Comment: You are using @ to_contact var in your action but trying to access it via @ to_contacts (Extra 's') in the partial. Am I missing something?